# How can I use concurrency to migrate database in Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlite, concurrency

I have a script used to migrate data from SQLite to Postgres. I just use a for loop to transfer tables one by one. Now, I want to experiment with transfering multiple tables in concurrency using threads, multiprocessing or asyncio to speed up the program to compare the runtimes between those ways.
How do you do one of those ways?

Here is my script:

```
import psycopg2, sqlite3, sys
import time
import multiprocessing



sqdb="C://Users//duongnb//Desktop//Python//SqliteToPostgreFull//testmydb6.db"
sqlike="table"
pgdb="testmydb11"
pguser="postgres"
pgpswd="1234"
pghost="127.0.0.1"
pgport="5432"


consq=sqlite3.connect(sqdb)
cursq=consq.cursor()

tabnames=[]
print() 
cursq.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type="table" AND name LIKE "%table%";')
tabgrab = cursq.fetchall()
for item in tabgrab:
    tabnames.append(item[0])
print(tabgrab)

def copyTable(table):
        print(table)
        cursq.execute("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name = ?;", (table,))
        create = cursq.fetchone()[0]
        cursq.execute("SELECT * FROM %s;" %table)
        rows=cursq.fetchall()
        colcount=len(rows[0])
        pholder='%s,'*colcount
        newholder=pholder[:-1]

        try:

            conpg = psycopg2.connect(database=pgdb, user=pguser, password=pgpswd,
                                host=pghost, port=pgport)
            curpg = conpg.cursor()
            curpg.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s;" %table)
            create = create.replace("AUTOINCREMENT", "")
            curpg.execute(create)
            curpg.executemany("INSERT INTO %s VALUES (%s);" % (table, newholder),rows)
            conpg.commit()

            if conpg:
                conpg.close()

        except psycopg2.DatabaseError as e:
            print ('Error %s' % e) 
            sys.exit(1)

        finally:
            print("Complete")    

consq.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    for table in tabnames:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target = copyTable, args = (table))
        p.start()
    for table in tabnames:
        p.join()
    print("All processes finished.")      

    duration = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"Duration {duration} seconds")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the inner of `for table in tabnames` into a function, say `copyTable`. Then you're able to use the `multiprocessing` package to parallelize your code. It should look something like this:

```
for table in tabnames:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target = copyTable, args = (table))
    p.start()
for table in tabnames:
    p.join()
print("All processes finished.")
```

But you can speed up your code even more if you use a `COPY` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) instead of the many `INSERT` commands.

Instead of the `multiprocessing` module, you can also use the `threading` module, which works quite similarly. Then you have threads instead of processes. Because of the interpreter lock I would expect a worse performance with this.

Comment: Thanks very much, it's helpfull, but I have got some error when making it follow your suggestion multiprocessing. Where am I wrong ?
Here my code above

Comment: @BinhDuong: `table` should be a obviously parameter to `copyTable`. Please take a look into Help (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) about using stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks, I passed the ```table``` parameter to the ```copyTable``` function: 
```def copyTable(table)``` but program still fails, could not transfer the tables. Can you help me edit it?

Comment: You should create a new request and include the errors and stacktrace.